# How to print values from an array in posts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

I needed a help, randomize values ​​of a array, and they were rewritten in the database in a particular field, this is the solution:

```
function gen_num()
{
  global $post;
  $mixnames = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', true );

  if ( '' == $mixnames ) {
    $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 3);
    $mixnames = $input[$rand_keys[1]];
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', $mixnames );
  }
  // DISPLAYS THE OUTCOME
  print $mixnames;
}
```

but it turns out that only prints a random value between 5 names, how do I print more values, I want the posts to be written one sequence can names, I can as well, but only with a name, a value, how to show more names?.

I thought so:

```
function gen_num()
{
  global $post;
  $mixnames = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', true );

  if ( '' == $mixnames ) {
    $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 3);
    $mixnames = $input[$rand_keys[1][2][3]];   
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', $mixnames );
  }
  // DISPLAYS THE OUTCOME
  print $mixnames;
}
```

It would be the problem here? .... D_keys [1] [2] [3]]; that does not work, it is only one idea :(

Comment: We are not *staff of stack overflow*.  We are community members *just like you*.

Comment: @cale_b Well, he needed a mother. Don't be so harsh.

Comment: forgiveness please, my English is bad, I meant people or friends or guys .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate strings

```
function gen_num()
{
  global $post;
  $mixnames = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', true );

  if ( '' == $mixnames ) {
    $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 3);
    $mixnames = $input[$rand_keys[0]].$input[$rand_keys[1]].$input[$rand_keys[2]];   
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fieldnames', $mixnames );
  }
  // DISPLAYS THE OUTCOME
  print $mixnames;
}
```

Comment: Thank You LTasty helped me a lot.

Comment: hi agains :), How do I add these values ​​in the tags field of posts? metapags be filled globally by these values? Already I racked my directory and files looking for something to add the call that value and nothing, and do not know without the name of the field no idea how to do :(

Comment: This function does not add the values in post fields in edit mode in wordpress dashboard, :( I'm want to add things manually to do SEO on Yoast but nothing appears on the dashboard, I made some changes but the values do not write permanently, they They change every refresh F5 :(